# Issue with D&D from list box to the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I'm using the following code to Drag & Drop from `ListBox` to `TextBox` which is working great, currently I got problem. When I drag item from the `ListBox` and by mistake drop it into the screen, but not in `TextBox`. Now I cant take the item which I drag to screen and do with it noting. I just need to pick new item from the list and drag it to `TextBox` and than I can drag it again. There is a way **`to check if the item which was drag is drop in the TextBox?`**

This is the code which I use and its calling to the `DoDragDrop` method. Even if I drag it to the wrong place in the screen (not to the TextBox), any idea?

```
private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    if (sender is ListBox)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var mySelectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem as User;

            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, mySelectedItem,
                                    DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty unclear, it makes very little sense to drag the entire listbox.  Dragging the selected item would be sensible.  You should do this with the PreviewMouseMove event if the mouse moved enough.  DoDragDrop() has a return value that says what happened.

Comment: @HansPassant-Thanks for your answer but Im not trying to drag the whole list box to somewhere ,I have list box with list of items and every time I try to drag only one item and this is working just fine but when by mistake instead of dragging the item to the text box I drag below the text box (like on label) ,I cannot pick the item again and drag it to the text box,just other item and than I can drag the previous item...any idea how to solve it?\

Comment: That's because you use the wrong event to get the drag started.  You won't get SelectionChanged again for the same item, the selection didn't change if you click it again.  Store the PreviousMouseDown position and use PreviewMouseMove to see the user starting to drag.

Comment: OK but how should I know if the Item was dragged to the right place which is the text box...

Comment: Repeating myself again: "DoDragDrop has a return value that says what happened".  Whether it is the "right place" is up to the textbox to decide.  It gives the thumbs up with its DragEnter event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant- I saw the parameter dragDropEffects but what should I do with it if the drop was to the wrong place,can you please provide example?

Comment: It is *completely* unclear to me why you care that the user fumbled the mouse.  The drag either completed or it didn't, you should not care.  Solve your event problem, that's the real issue.  Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17730544/17034).